# Defaulting a "var" for later use

Tags: c#

I ran across a situation in which I have a `var` that needs to be defined in an `if-else` block. However, you can't do,

```
var myVar;

if(myBool) { myVar = 0; }
else { myVar = 1; }
```

because you get an error, "Implicitly typed variables must be initialized." Now, I could declare the variable to start as what is in the `if` block, then just not do anything inside said `if` block, but that just seems like bad practice. Suggestions?

Also, note that this is a simplified scenario, and I **can't** do something simple like the following,

```
var myVar = 0;
if(!myBool) { myVar = 1; }
```

edit: Trying to be fancy with enums. The `if-else` block would set `myVar` to an enum.

Comment: You could... declare the type.

Comment: `var` means "infer the type from the initializer". You can't declare an uninitialized variable with `var`. So initialize it, or give it an explicit type. If you want to use `var` to declare a variable of indeterminate type, *you can't do that, because that is not what it does*. Use `object` for that. Or maybe `dynamic`.

Comment: `var` must be given a value, otherwise it cannot infer the type and won't compile. just do `int myVar;`.

Comment: Curious to know why you can't do the simple thing.

Comment: "I could declare the variable to start as what is in the if block, then just not do anything inside said if block, but that just seems like bad practice.": **I disagree!** It seems to me to be excellent practice. I encourage you to it that way.

Comment: Why can't you invert the `if`? It should _always_ be possible to negate a condition.

Comment: The given scenario is greatly simplified, in both using ints, and the condition. In practice I'm actually using enums

Comment: Is it that you need to assign the var from among many Enum types?

Comment: @RamblinRose Yes (if by type you mean `public enum MyEnum`), doing `myVar = typeof(MyEnum);`

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `:?`, which is more functional:

```
var myVar = myBool ? 0 : 1;
```

If your logic is more complicated, and you want to avoid many nested `?:`, I would suggest making a small static function:

```
private static int computeWhatever(bool myBool)
{
    // etc...
}

var myVar = computeWhatever(myBool);
```

Sadly this is is something which can be written much more compactly in other languages, particularly those with "[do expressions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:do_expressions)". Do expressions allow a block of statements to be evaluated as an expression, with minimal boiler-plate.

For example, in the JavaScript proposal:

```
x = do { let t = f(); t * t + 1 };
print(do { let x = f(); g(x, x) });
```

If you want to stay in the .NET world and use this construct, F# would be the best choice.

---

In response to some of the comments, I would argue that declaring a variable as uninitialized before the block is poor style:

```
int myVar;
if (!myBool)
{
    myVar = 1;
}
```

If your variables are always initialized, and ideally never changed, then they are much easier to reason about. As an added bonus, code is easier to refactor when it is side-effect free. If you always prefer `?:` then you are on the right track. Just don't be too dogmatic!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't initialize the variable, the compiler can't tell what type it should have.

If you declare it with an actual type instead of `var`, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

So because you can't do this, use **explicit** typing and keep going:

```
int myVar;

if(myBool) { myVar = 0; }
else { myVar = 1; }
```

The coolest code is the one that's feasible (implicit typing wasn't introduced as a silver bullet to any case in the world).